# Time converter is not working, giving me "could not convert string to float"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to convert times from hours, minutes, seconds, to just seconds but I can't figure out why I'm getting the error "could not convert string to float"

```
tmp1 = t.split('.')[0]
tmp2 = tmp1.split(':')
if len(tmp2)>1:
    seconds = 60.0*60.0*float(tmp2[0])+60.0*float(tmp2[1])+float(tmp1[1])
if len(tmp2)>2:
    seconds = 60.0*60.0*float(tmp2[0])+60.0*float(tmp2[1])+float(tmp2[2])

print(t, tmp1, tmp2, seconds)

02:38.0 02:38.0 ['02', '38'] 9482.0
02:28:28 02:28:28 ['02', '28', '28'] 8908.0
02:10.21 02:10 ['02', '10'] 7802.0
```

Comment: What is the value of `t`?

Comment: @Błotosmętek t is the time that I am feeding it, the time is formatted as 2:34:56 or 2:34.56

Comment: Questions that rely on data should include a minimal example of the data. - What is `t`? Please read [mcve].

Comment: If you are using an IDE that has debugging facilities, now would be a good time to start learning how to use those also. Sometimes making intermediate values instead of a single long line helps because you can print those intermediate values which helps troubleshooting.

Comment: Can `t` have both forms - `'hh:mm:ss'` and `'hh:mm.ddd'`? where `'mm.ddd'` is fractional minutes?

Answer (score 1):

`tmp1[1]` is the second character of the string `tmp1`. If that is a `:` or other non-digit, it won't be able to convert it to a float.

If your input is `2:34.56`, `tmp[1]` is equal to `:` when you run

```
seconds = 60.0*60.0*float(tmp2[0])+60.0*float(tmp2[1])+float(tmp1[1])
```

You likely are intending to run the `len(tmp2)>2` condition only when it does not run the other condition. One solution would be to use equals instead of greater than.

```
if len(tmp2) == 2:
    seconds = 60.0*60.0*float(tmp2[0])+60.0*float(tmp2[1])+float(tmp1[1])    
elif len(tmp2) == 3:
    seconds = 60.0*60.0*float(tmp2[0])+60.0*float(tmp2[1])+float(tmp2[2])
```

The other option would be to swap the conditions (as @Błotosmętek has done in their answer). Either way, you should use `elif` (else if) instead of `if` for the second condition so that the second condition won't run if the first condition has run.

Comment: How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Do not try the second form if the first is executed:

```
if len(tmp2)>2:
    seconds = 60.0*60.0*float(tmp2[0])+60.0*float(tmp2[1])+float(tmp2[2])
elif len(tmp2)>1:
    seconds = 60.0*60.0*float(tmp2[0])+60.0*float(tmp2[1])+float(tmp1[1])
```